# how to compare 2 array for multiple select in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

hi how to compare 2 array javascript for multiple select
first array is account : `['ID': 2,'nama': 'test']['ID': 3,'nama': 'test1']['ID': 4,'nama': 'test4']['ID': 5,'nama': 'test5']`

second array is account_selected : `['ID': 2,'nama': 'test']['ID': 5,'nama': 'test']`

how to know on first array have id to second array, i have to code like this but just array [0] can compare

```
    $.each( account, function( i, value ) {
        var data = value;

        if (data.ID == account_selected[0].ID){
            temp += '<option selected  value="'+data.ID+'" id="account_id'+data.ID+'" value="'+data.ID+'" >'+data.nama+'</option>'
        } else {
            temp += '<option  value="'+data.ID+'" id="account_id'+data.ID+'" value="'+data.ID+'" >'+data.nama+'</option>'
        }
    });
```

this code just first compare first array account_selected ,i want to option is selected if data same

Comment: `account_selected[0]` should be `account_selected[index]`

Comment: error bro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ID')

Comment: That means there is no match. You should also check (first) that `index > -1`. So `if (index > -1 && data.ID == account_selected[index].ID)`. Why do you use jQuery functions for this? Native JavaScript has functions for this... Use jQuery for DOM manipulation, but not for working with or looping over arrays.

Comment: can you explain in jsfiddle?

Comment: The Array structure you provided seems to  be invalid, Also the explanation could be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested array to match check the validation.

```
  var account = [
    {'ID': 2,'nama': 'test'},
    {'ID': 3,'nama': 'test1'},
    {'ID': 4,'nama': 'test4'},  
    {'ID': 5,'nama': 'test5'},
  ];
  var account_selected = [
    {'ID': 2,'nama': 'test'},
    {'ID': 5,'nama': 'test'}
  ];

  $.each( account, function( i, valueAccount ) {
    var dataAccount = valueAccount;

    $.each( account_selected , function( i, valueSelected ) {
      var dataSelected = valueSelected;
      var temp = '';
      if( (dataSelected.ID == dataAccount.ID) &&  (dataSelected.nama == dataAccount.nama) ){
      temp += '<option selected  value="'+dataSelected.ID+'" id="account_id'+dataAccount.ID+'" value="'+dataAccount.ID+'" >'+dataAccount.nama+'</option>'
      }else{
      temp += '<option  value="'+dataAccount.ID+'" id="account_id'+dataAccount.ID+'" value="'+dataAccount.ID+'" >'+dataAccount.nama+'</option>'
      }
      console.log(temp);
    });
  });
```